# Python: How can I add a counter to the replacement argument of re.sub()

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing, auto-increment

I'd like to add ids to html tags. For example, I'd like to change:

```
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
```

to

```
<p id="1">First paragraph</p>
<p id="2">Second paragraph</p>
<p id="3">Third paragraph</p>
```

IIRC, it's possible to use a lambda function to achieve this functionality, but I can't remember the exact syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Count and replace regular expression in same pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897536/python-count-and-replace-regular-expression-in-same-pass)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use an HTML parser, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

The idea is to iterate over all paragraphs using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) for indexing, starting with `1`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for index, p in enumerate(soup.find_all('p'), start=1):
    p['id'] = index

print soup
```

Prints:

```
<p id="1">First paragraph</p>
<p id="2">Second paragraph</p>
<p id="3">Third paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use regex, the quick and dirty solution would be to use a global variable, like so:

```
i = 0

def replace(match):
    global i
    i += 1
    return '<p id="{0}">'.format(i)

re.sub(pattern, replace, your_string)
```

Alternatively, you could create a custom class that "pretends" to be a function using `__call__` and define the counter to be a field:

```
class Replace(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def __call__(self, match):
        self.counter += 1
        return '<p id="{0}">'.format(self.counter)

replace = Replace()
re.sub(pattern, replace, your_string)
```

Comment: This solution will not work correctly if there are no matches - I'll post the fix soon

Answer (score 2):

Not very generic, but should work

```
def sub_p(string):
   def inc(m, i=[0]):
      i[0] += 1
      return '<p id="%i">' % i[0]
   return re.sub(r"<p>", inc, string)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complement to the @Michael0x2a 's answer

There is a major bug in his code, in particular: *If nothing was replaced, the counter will still return 1*. As well as a few minor issues

To work around the main bug, one can utilise the fast hashing algorithms. I'll use Adler32.

```
import re
import zlib

class Replace(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def __call__(self, match):
        self.counter += 1
        return '<p id="{0}">'.format(self.counter)

replace = Replace()
old = zlib.adler32(your_string)
replaced = re.sub(pattern, replace, your_string)
new = zlib.adler32(replaced)

if(old == new):
    replace.counter = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub()`

```
x=['<p>First paragraph</p>', '<p>Second paragraph</p>', '<p>Third paragraph</p>']
for i, p in enumerate(x,start=1):
...     re.sub(r'^<p>', '<p id="%d">'%i, p)
... 
'<p id="1">First paragraph</p>'
'<p id="2">Second paragraph</p>'
'<p id="3">Third paragraph</p>'
```

Comment: But since it involves html tags i would prefer using beautifulsoup as in @alecxe answer

Comment: how did the paragraphs get into a list in the first place?

Comment: @tdelaney the answer demonstrate how to substitute `id` for input tags using regex. Op never mentioned anything about changing every `p` in a document or somthing